# MySQL + PhP - search multiple words

Tags: php, mysql, string

Good morning!

Would like to perform a search with several words that will be passed on the html input.

Examples:

- If you enter `"gfilgueiras"` will return 3 records.
- If you enter `"informativo gfilgueiras"` will return 2 records.
- If you enter `"gfilgueiras :: 2"` will return only 1 record.

I do a direct search for viewLogs.

I tried the concat, but did not succeed.

I'm sorry if my English is not good, I'm using a translator.

**Sample Data:**

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you all.

Comment: Please share the query you are using to search.

Comment: What is the order you wish to search? Like <serverid>[login]<ip> ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM viewLogs WHERE concat(ip,login, descricao, data, hora, acao, severidade) REGEXP "gfilgueiras"

Comment: have you tried like '%gfilgueiras%' instead of REGEXP "gfilgueiras"?

Comment: It's work, but i need more arguments in my query
example: gfilgueiras erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not possible, you need to use AND on your WHERE clause, assuming the search word delimiter is space.

```
// $searchWord is informativo gfilgueiras
if(!empty($searchWord)) {

     // separates the searched word by space and puts it in array, if no space, put in array.
     $searchWords = strpos($searchWord,' ') !== false ? explode(' ',$searchWord) : array($searchWord);

     // this is just an example, use sql prepared statement for this
     $sqlString = "SELECT * FROM viewLogs WHERE concat(ip,login, descricao, data, hora, acao, severidade) REGEXP '$searchWord[0]' ";

     if(count($searchWords) > 0) {
         if(isset($searchWords[0])) {
             foreach($searchWords as $index => $searchWord) {
                 if($index > 0) {
                     // this is just an example, use sql prepared statement for this
                     $sqlString .= "AND WHERE concat(ip,login, descricao, data, hora, acao, severidade) REGEXP '$searchWord'";
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM viewLogs WHERE concat(all field you want ) REGEXP "gfilgueiras"
```

Comment: It's work, but i need more arguments
example: gfilgueiras erro